# progressbar setvisible not working

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
>

<ProgressBar 
  android:id="@+id/aPBar"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"/>

 ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my onCreate method I do this to hide the ProgressBar at first:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.achievements_screen, null);

progressBar=(ProgressBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.aPBar);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

But the `ProgressBar` is still visible all the time ... I also tried `View.GONE`.

When i set

```
android:visible="gone"
```

in the XML file, the `ProgressBar` doesnt show up, but I can't make it appear with

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Comment: looks it should work can you give a bit ore idea where you are using (adding) this layout view

Comment: ok, I got it working by using `progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.aPBar);`
instead of `progressBar=(ProgressBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.aPBar);` but I have no idea why this works. im adding this layout view in the onCreate of my activity after super.onCreate and setContentView

Answer (score 2):

You are inflating a new view using the Layout Inflater. This is **NOT** the view currently on the screen.

Therefore changing it's visibility won't affect the screen UI.

Further up your Activity you must have called `setContentView` and **this is** the layout that is visible on your UI.

Therefore calling:

`findViewById` will return your progress bar on the screen, but calling `layout.findViewById` will return that layouts progress bar (correctly) but that is not the progressBar you can see on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
rootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround for me was to hide the view in XML and then unhide/hide it at runtime when needed:
`android:visibility="gone"`